# Why is my JavaScript function "a" not defined?

Tags: javascript

When I call my JavaScript function B, the JavaScript console in Firefox said that function A is not defined, but on Chrome browser it's defined. And when I call function "A" in body segment:

```
<input type="button" onclick="A()" value=" ..A.. ">
```

Firefox said that function B is not defined. Why?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            function B() {
                alert(" hi B ");
                document.write('<br><br><input type="button" onClick="A()" value=" ..A..">');
            };

            function A() {
                alert(" hi A");
                document.write('<br><br><input type="button" onclick="B()" value=" ..b..">');
                if (window.WebCL == undefined) {
                    alert("Unfortunately your system does not support WebCL. ");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" onclick="B()" value=" ..B.. ">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F8Dwk/)

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz for that fiddle, both chrome and FF give me the alert, none gave error

Comment: @Pheonix: did you get _both_ the "hi B" and "hi A" alerts?  On FF11, I get the "hi B" alert, but console error when I push button A.

Comment: There should be some more subtle way to handle these kinds of problems. You can also attach events to the DOM: http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/domevents or http://api.jquery.com/category/events/

Answer (score 4):

The first write clears the content of the document, resulting in function A being undefined

Comment: This might be the reason. But this should not happen as the function is defined before it gets erased from `<script>` node

Comment: check it with fiddle. The script are initially there, but no more after clicking B (checked with FF)

Comment: Function A should not be undefined after the script is erased. Becasue when its defied its reference is attached to window object. It should have existed.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are calling `document.write` after the page has loaded, which effectively wipes out the existing content of the page, including the embedded script.  You should be using [DOM manipulation methods](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/dombasics) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

var  A = function() {
   alert(" hi A");
   document.write('<br><br><input type="button" onclick="B()" value=" ..b..">');
   if (window.WebCL == undefined) {
     alert("Unfortunately your system does not support WebCL. ");
     return false;
   }
 }  

 function B(){
   alert(" hi B ");     
   document.body.innerHTML = ('<br><br><input type="button" onClick="new A()" value=" ..A..">'); 
 }

    </script>
    </head>

<body>
   <input type="button" onclick="B()" value=" ..B.. ">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I accepted  the Ehsan's form, and I go to study the DOM methods, thanks